# Javascript/ D3.js / forced directed graph with label

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a forced directed graph by using D3. I have already created a graph with no labels, but once I tried to put label on graph, it messed up whole code and the graph doesn't even appear. I wrote the code after checking several documents, but I don't know where to fix it anymore. Anyone familiar with D3 would appreciate it if you could let me know which part of this code went wrong.

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 v5 force simulation</title>
  <style>
    text {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="500" height="600"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
 
  var nodesData = [
    {id:"Korea", "group": 1, "value": 10},
    {id:"USA", "group": 1, "value": 5},
    {id:"France", "group": 1, "value": 5},
    {id:"UK", "group": 1, "value": 5},
    {id:"Japan", "group": 1, "value": 20},
    {id:"Turkey", "group": 1, "value": 5},

  ]

  var linksData = [
    { "source": 'Korea', "target": 'USA'},
    { "source": 'UK', "target": 'USA' },
    { "source": 'France', "target": 'Turkey' },
    { "source": 'Korea', "target": 'UK' },
    { "source": 'Japan', "target": 'Turkey' },
    { "source": 'Japan', "target": 'Korea' }
  ]

<---added---->
 var svg = d3.select("svg"),
     width =  +svg.attr("width"),
     height = +svg.attr("height");

 <---changed---->
  var link = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(linksData)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "black");


  <---changed---->
  var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(nodesData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    
<---changed---->
 var circles = node.append("circle")
    .data(nodesData)
    .attr("r", d => d.value)
    .attr("fill", "LightSalmon")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

<---added---->
var labels = node.append("text")
    .text(function(d){return d.id;});
    



  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(200, 150));

  simulation
    .nodes(nodesData)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(linksData);


  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }


  function dragstarted(d) {
    if(!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if(!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

<Original Code - forced directed graph without label>
To put label, I just changed few points. Originally, node and link were set separately, but they were grouped together to put label.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 v5 force simulation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="400" height="300"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  // 1. Data
  var nodesData = [
    {id:"Korea", "group": 1, "value":10},
    {id:"USA", "group": 1,"value":5},
    {id:"France", "group": 1,"value":5},
    {id:"UK", "group": 1,"value":5},
    {id:"Japan", "group": 1,"value":20},
    {id:"Turkey", "group": 1,"value":5},

  ]

  var linksData = [
    { "source": 'Korea', "target": 'USA'},
    { "source": 'UK', "target": 'USA' },
    { "source": 'France', "target": 'Turkey' },
    { "source": 'Korea', "target": 'UK' },
    { "source": 'Japan', "target": 'Turkey' },
    { "source": 'Japan', "target": 'Korea' }
  ]

  // 2. svg
  var link = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(linksData)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "black");

  var node = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodesData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", d=> d.value)
    .attr("fill", "LightSalmon")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

  // 3. forceSimulation
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(200, 150));

  simulation
    .nodes(nodesData)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(linksData);

  // 4. forceSimulation 
  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }

  // 5. drag event
  function dragstarted(d) {
    if(!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if(!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your nodes are `g` elements, you need to use the `transform`  property to move them around. We use the `translate(x,y)` transformation which moves it around.

```
  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})` });
  }
```

We're now translating the `g` elements, so call the drag handler on them directly:

```
  var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(nodesData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 v5 force simulation</title>
  <style>
    text {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="500" height="600"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
 
  var nodesData = [
    {id:"Korea", "group": 1, "value": 10},
    {id:"USA", "group": 1, "value": 5},
    {id:"France", "group": 1, "value": 5},
    {id:"UK", "group": 1, "value": 5},
    {id:"Japan", "group": 1, "value": 20},
    {id:"Turkey", "group": 1, "value": 5},

  ]

  var linksData = [
    { "source": 'Korea', "target": 'USA'},
    { "source": 'UK', "target": 'USA' },
    { "source": 'France', "target": 'Turkey' },
    { "source": 'Korea', "target": 'UK' },
    { "source": 'Japan', "target": 'Turkey' },
    { "source": 'Japan', "target": 'Korea' }
  ]

 var svg = d3.select("svg"),
     width =  +svg.attr("width"),
     height = +svg.attr("height");

  var link = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(linksData)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "black");


  var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(nodesData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));
    
 var circles = node.append("circle")
    .data(nodesData)
    .attr("r", d => d.value)
    .attr("fill", "LightSalmon")

var labels = node.append("text")
    .text(function(d){return d.id;});
    



  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(200, 150));

  simulation
    .nodes(nodesData)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(linksData);


  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})` });
  }


  function dragstarted(d) {
    if(!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if(!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you. Yes, as you advised, there was misspelled point. Sorry that was just my mistake. But what I want to create is forced graph with labeling(Label = id). 
I added my original code on the above (original code is for the forced directed graph without labeling). And I tried to change this code to put label on it. However I could not find the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've updated my answer in a way that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!. It is working now. I have spent several days for this.. Thanks.
And I just curious do you know why node is vibrated a lot when it is dragged?
For example the forced directed graph( original code) is move smoothly when it is dragged..

Comment: I really appreciated it. it is working now. I upvoted (Sorry I did not know this). thank you.

Comment: Thank you! You can also accept my answer to your question by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers